# Git command customizing in PyCharm

Tags: git, pycharm

I'm using Git under PyCharm.

However, when I look at what PyCharm does with the Git ("Console" tab of the version control view), there's a bunch of added options to them. For example, a Fetch command is:

```
git -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false fetch origin
--progress --prune
```

And I can't find a way to fully control the way PyCharm generates these options.
Is it possible to change these default options under PyCharm, or are they hardcoded?
Also, has anyone used the "External tools" interface to make their own git commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version control integration feature of PyCharm parses the output of Git, and for the parsing to work, it requires the output to be in a specific format. The options added by PyCharm ensure that the output is in that format. Because of that, there is no possibility to customize them.

You can indeed use "External tools" to run any external commands from PyCharm, including Git.